# AppleScript - Why the progress dialog box does not show up on script app when automating a third party app?

Tags: applescript, progress-bar

I have a script automating a user interface of a third party app. In the script, there is a progress bar that shows up in the Script Editor as it should. But it does not show as a dialog box when I export the script as an app and launch it.

The third party app has it's own dialog boxes, I wonder if they interfer with the progress dialog box from the script.

Can you tell what is wrong?

```
repeat with idx from 1 to length of myList
    
    set progress total steps to length of myList
    set progress completed steps to idx
    set progress description to "Processing media..."
    set progress additional description to "Converting " & mediaName
    
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process myApp
            tell window myApp
            
                --Things happening here
                
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    
end repeat
```

Comment: Your script (minus whatever "myApp" does) shows up for me - is the dialog getting buried behind the third-party app?

Comment: You should activate your third-party app before any attempts to begin GUI scripting of its dialog box or some window. That is, add **set frontmost to true** after **tell application process myApp**. Because in other case, frontmost is progress window of script app

Comment: Well. if the name of the process is indicated wrongly, you should got this error... The link is indicated by you wrongly as well

Comment: So I've activated the app this the process [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AutomatetheUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH69-SW1).

Then when I `set frontmost to true`, I get the error `Can’t set frontmost of \"ZaxConvert\" to true." number -10006 from frontmost of "ZaxConvert"`

Answer (score 0):

Example with Handbrake's window, because I still should guess what app and window you use.

```
set mediaName to "myMedia"
set myApp to "HandBrake"
set myList to {"Marlow", "Maddie", "Sammy", "Stuey", "Jessie", "Tolstoy"}

set progress total steps to length of myList
set progress description to "Processing media..."
set progress additional description to "Converting " & mediaName

repeat with idx from 1 to length of myList
    
    tell application "System Events" to tell process myApp
        set frontmost to true
        tell window 1
            -- Things happening here
            set a to value of static text 1 of group 1
            display notification text 1 thru 20 of (paragraph 2 of a)
        end tell
    end tell
    set progress completed steps to idx
    tell me to activate
    delay 3
    
end repeat
```

NOTE: you can't run progress window always on foreground because you want retrieve some info from other window using GUI scripting.

Comment: This helped to set it in a better way but unfortunately hasn't solved the issue. But I figured that if I used `tell me to activate`, that it brings the progress dialogue to the front. However, it stops/pauses the script. Is there a way to have the progress dialogue to constantly run in the foreground, without the script pausing/stopping?

Comment: So the script should be running through the whole list without interruption, which is why I can't use `tell application myApp to display dialogue "Hello on the front"`. Instead, I use `tell me to activate` to bring the progress dialogue to the front and the script pauses as soon as the progress bar is brought to the front. I think it wants the third party app it is automating to be right at the front for the script to keep running. I just hope this wouldn't be a problem. I don't understand why?

Comment: @userX: I have updated my answer. This is due to the fact that you are running and in a hurry as when catching fleas, instead of trying to understand what is at stake. In the answer, the example is more specific, and if you don't understand it either, then this is no longer my fault.

Comment: Ok, well thank you for your help so far anyway. You've really been helpful and I'm very thankful for this. It's helped me a lot to progress and hope that I can give it back to the community somehow.